# How to generate an OpenAPI documentation from a JSON:API compliant response?

Tags: openapi, json-api

Given a .json response from a resource that implements JSON:API (as in the [official example](https://jsonapi.org/)), what is the optimal way to generate a .yaml OpenAPI documentation from the given file?